# Best custom dynamic grid for MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, dynamic, datagrid

.Net MVC application also running Linq-to-SQL.

I have seen many articles on grids that will operate in this environment but none that will capture data - all simply display and sort/order.

I need to dynamically add project codes as columns and have days of the week as rows.  The individual cells will contain hours worked - yup this is a simple timesheet application.  I do not think the AJAX route is that easy considering MVC and Linq-to-SQL and the fact that each user will need to choose which projects they worked on that week to add them to the grid.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx). It's quite capable of sorting, paging, dynamically updating data, ajax, filtering, ...

Comment: Server error on the suggested link  :P

Comment: The site mentioned is not maintained by me. I would currently rather advice the Kendo UI MVC grid as we're already 8 years further in time since I gave this answer.